# SQL Server 2014 Upgrade Advisor failing

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, sql-server-2014

I've installed SQL Server 2014 Enterprise on a VM and am trying to install the Upgrade Advisor.

Directions indicate that I should run `SqlUA.msi` but I get the following error:

> Setup is missing prerequisites:
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Transact-SQL-ScriptDom, which is not installed by Upgrade Advisor Setup. To continue, install SQL Server 2014 Transact-SQL ScriptDom from below hyperlink and then run the Upgrade Advisor Setup operation again :
>
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=296473.

That just takes me to the download page. There is no ScriptDom file, but a further search showed me that they mean SQLDOM. So I installed SQLDOM.msi from that page above and got the following error:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL-ScriptDom
>
> Installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL-ScriptDom failed because a higher version already exists on the machine. To proceed, uninstall the higher version and then run Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom Setup again.

Well, that was pretty confusing. First I'm told I don't have it, then I'm told I'm trying to install an older version. I've rebooted the VM and my local laptop a bunch but without assist. Microsoft Support told me they don't support upgrade advisor.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Feature Pack page, here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295

Click the Download button, then look for the download named "SqlDom.msi"; the x64 version is about 1/3 of the way down, the x86 version is about 80-85% of the way down.

These should be the latest versions of the ScriptDom.

Comment: Thanks - I tried this and I got the same error when install upgrade advisor. It looked like the SqlDom.msi was already installed when I installed it again (asked me to repair rather than install). Then I noticed that I was downloading the x86 UA rather than the x64 version - x64 version worked with no errors.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I didn't notice that there 2 versions of each and they are well spread out in the list of all the possible downloads. The x64 is in the directory structure part of the name, not in the name itself.  Very bad interface.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, installed x64 sqldom.msi - it didn't work. So I then installed x86 version and the upgrade advisor worked. This was on server 2012R2 with SQL2012 x64.

Answer (score 0):

The file Eng_Microsoft_SQLServer_TransactSql_ScriptDom_dll_32 cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file redist.cab. This could 
indicate a network error, an error reading from installation media, or a problem with this package.